# Is there a conceptual limit on the amount of energy put into a single proton acceleration?

Tags: speed-of-light

Objects with mass need an unlimited amount of energy to approach the speed of light. Does it mean the energy of an entire galaxy can be put into a single proton acceleration? What about an unlimited energy increase? Would the proton continue approaching the speed of light forever?

Comment: Regarding the main question, I will ask: Is it possible to produce an infinite amount of energy in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, yes, you can dump as much energy as you like into a single proton. It doesn't mean a whole lot, because you could also, in principle, dump enough energy in to yourself going the other way, and the apparent motion of the proton will be the same. The fact that the proton is charged introduces a little wrinkle in that accelerating it will produce electromagnetic radiation, but that's not significant.

In practice, though, when you try to keep accelerating the proton you'll run in to problems. At the [Large Hadron Collider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider) (LHC), for instance, they have to make it colder inside of the tube than deep space ($1.9\operatorname{K}$ in the LHC vs. $2.7\operatorname{K}$ in the [Cosmic Microwave Background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) [CMB]). Why? Because even when you have a vacuum of matter, there are photons zipping around in a [photon gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_gas) that has a [black body spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body). Because protons are charged, they will interact with the photons directly. This means that the gas will provide a form of dynamical friction that will, very slowly, bring the proton into its reference frame through collisions.

More importantly, as the proton goes faster compared to the rest frame of the black body, the proton gains access to more ways to interact with the photons. The first channel that opens up is [pair production of electron-positrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production). The most famous one, though, is known as the [GZK cutoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greisen%E2%80%93Zatsepin%E2%80%93Kuzmin_limit), where the proton colliding with the photon gas produces [pions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion) As more ways to collide with the gas become available, the rate at which the proton is slowed increases.

It's even worse for electrons because of their lower mass, the same way that a feather will decelerate faster than an object comparable size and shape with higher mass.

In principle, the same holds true for neutrons (which have a magnetic moment), and neutrinos (which would interact with the photons indirectly though the weak force), though that very same lack of charge also makes them harder to accelerate.

Long story short, the faster you go, the more the universe becomes effectively opaque as the CMB ahead of you gets [blue-shifted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect) into higher and higher energy radiation. In principle, if you go fast enough, you'll be running into a head-wind of high energy gamma rays (really hard radiation) that will slow you down as it rips you apart.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on neutrinos interacting with photons weakly?

Comment: @safesphere To interact with photons directly an electric charge or magnetic dipole moment (all fundamental particles that have one have the other, as far as I know). For a neutrino to interact with a photon requires a higher order process where there's at least one loop in the Feynman diagram. Because the lowest order loop will involve a virtual $\mathrm{W}$ boson, it is extremely low probability. For more, see: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/284436/47360

Comment: For electron, Bremstrahlung is the biggest problem at a synchrotron since it scales as the inverse fourth power of the particle mass.